# Scrapy - a lot of DNS lookup errors

Tags: python, dns, scrapy

**Problem:**
I'm getting a lot (really a lot) of DNS lookup errors, although sites are online.
This is the sample output:

```
ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET http://matthewvielkind.dev> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: matthewvielkind.dev.
ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET http://tureus.com> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: tureus.com.
ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET http://tripbuilderpro.com> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: no results for hostname lookup: tripbuilderpro.com.
```

**Relevant code:**

```
def get_urls_from_csv(self, from_file):
    with open(from_file, 'rU') as csv_file:
        data = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in data:
            yield "http://" + row[1]

def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.http.Request(url=start_url, callback=self.parse_ok) for start_url in self.get_urls_from_csv(self.from_file)]

def parse_ok(self, response):
    if self.search in response.text:
        url = [response.request.url]
        #other things to do
        
        for item in zip(url):
            scraped_info = {
                'URL:': item[0],
            }

            yield scraped_info
```

**settings.py**

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10
LOGSTATS_INTERVAL = 5
```

**Question** Where I made mistake?

Comment: Should be a connection issue or DNS server failure, nothing related to your code.

Comment: I thought that, but I have tried also to run in on Digitalocean and AWS. It was more or less the same.

Comment: Could means that the target DNS is down or uses some kind of abuse protection.

Comment: Might be that. From your experience, would proxy pool solve or at least lower DNS lookup errors?

Comment: Well, as I wrote earlier t is not a programming issue and therefor it leaves the topics Stack Overflow is covering.